# How to cache individual Django REST API POSTs for bulk_create?

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a Django REST API endpoint. It receives a JSON payload eg.

```
{ "data" : [0,1,2,3] }
```

This is decoded in a views.py function and generates a new database object like so (pseudo code):

```
newobj = MyObj.(col0 = 0, col1= 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3)
newobj.save()
```

In tests, it is 20x faster to create a list of x1000 newobjs, then do a bulk create:

```
Myobj.objects.bulk_create(newobjs, 1000)
```

So, the question is how to save individual POSTs somewhere in Django ready for batch writes when we have 1000 of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the above responses, the answers included some of what was suggested, but is a superset, so here's a summary.

This is really about creating a FIFO. [memcached](https://memcached.org/) turns out to be unsuitable (after trying) because only [redis](https://redis.io/) has a list function that enables this, explained nicely [here](http://peter-hoffmann.com/2012/python-simple-queue-redis-queue.html).

Also note that the [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/) built in cache does not support the redis list api calls.

So we need a new docker-compose.yml entry to add redis:

```
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379/tcp
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Then in views.py we add: (note the use of redis [rpush](https://redis.io/commands/rpush))

```
import redis
...
redis_host=os.environ['REDIS_HOST']
redis_port = 6379
redis_password = ""
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port, password=redis_password, decode_responses=True)
...
def write_post_to_redis(request):
payload = json.loads(request.body)
r.rpush("df",json.dumps(payload))
```

So this pushes the received payload into the redis in-memory cache. We now need to read (or pop ) it and write to the postgres database. So we need a process that wakes up every n seconds and checks. For this we need Django [background_task](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). First, install it with:

```
pipenv install django-background-tasks
```

And add to the installed apps of the settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'background_task',
```

Then run a migrate to add the background task tables:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Now in views.py, add:

```
from background_task import background
from background_task.models import CompletedTask
```

And add the function to write the cached data to the postgres database, note the decorator which states it should run in the background every 5 seconds. Also note use of redis [lpop](https://redis.io/commands/LPOP).

```
@background(schedule=5)
def write_cached_samples():
...
payload = json.loads(r.lpop('df'))
# now do your write of payload to postgres
... and delete the completed tasks or we'll have a big db leak
CompletedTask.objects.all().delete()
```

In order to start the process up, add the following to the base of urls.py:

```
write_cached_samples(repeat=10, repeat_until=None)
```

Finally, because the background task needs a separate process, we duplicate the django docker container in docker-compose.yml but replace the asgi server run command with the background process run command.

```
django_bg:
      image: my_django
      command: >
        sh -c "python manage.py process_tasks"
      ...
```

In summary we add two new docker containers, one for the redis in-memory cache, and one to run the django background tasks. We use the *redis* *lists* *rpush* and *lpop* functions to create a FIFO with the API receive pushing and a background task popping.

There was a small issue where nginx was hooking up to the wrong django container, rectified by stopping and restarting the background container, some issue where docker networking routing is wrongly initialising.

Next I am replacing the Django HTTP API endpoint with a Go one to see how much of a speed up we get, as the Daphne ASGI server is hitting max CPU at only 100 requests per sec.

Comment: I went further and implemented the write_post_to_redis in a separate Go app. Massive speed up over using the Django REST API (x100 at least).

Answer (score 1):

You can cache it with Memcached or with Redis, for example.
But you will need to write some kind of service that checks how many new items in the cache and if there are more than e.g. 1000 -> insert it.

So:

1. POST are populating a cache
2. Service getting new items from the cache and then inserting them in the persistence database.

Do you really need it?
What will happen if data already exist? If data is corrupted? How the user will know about this?

Comment: Thanks Victor, looking at Eshaan7's answer below, turns out that the built in Django cache can use memcache (and I think Redis too)

Answer (score 1):

> save individual POSTs somewhere in Django ready for batch writes when we have 1000 of them

You can,

1. use [django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#basic-usage),
2. maintain a `CSV` file using python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
3. you probably want to maintain the order of the posts, so you can use [persist-queue](https://github.com/peter-wangxu/persist-queue) package.

But as Victor mentioned as well, why? Why are you so concerned about speeds of `SQL Insert` which are pretty fast anyway ?

Ofcourse, `bulk_create` is *much* faster because it takes a single network call to your DB server and adds all the rows in a single [SQL transaction](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/controlling-transactions.php) but it only makes sense to use it when you actually have bunch of data to be added together.  - At the end, you must save the data *somewhere* which is gonna take some processing time one way or another.

Because there are many disadvantages to your approach:

- you risk losing the data
- you will not be able to achieve `UNIQUE` or any other constraint on your table.
- your users won't get instant feedback on creating a post.
- you cannot show/access the posts in useful way if they are not stored in your primary DB.

#### EDIT

Use a fast cache like Redis to maintain a list of the entries, in your `api_view` you can call `cache.get` to get the current list, append object to it and then call `cache.set` to update it. After this add a check that whenever `len(list) >= 1000 == True` call `bulk_create`. You might also want to consider using [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch) for such enormous amount of data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eshaan7, you make valid points but in this case we have approx 1000 sources sending 5second updates with no hard real time requirement to visualize the data. And with this load, a 1000x cache will still only be a 5 s delay

Comment: @NickT updated my answer with some more tips.

Comment: Thanks, just thinking about multi-thread access. I assume the API endpoint will run in a thread per HTTP POST. So if we save into one single cache key then it may fall over if multiple threads are trying to access it simultaneously. Unless this is handled in the cache system ..? I will give it a go and see what happens using locust.io to load it up.